# User agent classification using switch (true)

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I've seen usage of `switch(true)` multiple times and have used it myself today instead of multiple `else`if`s. Here is the case I used it for:

```
var isChrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') != -1;
var isSafari = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('safari') != -1;
var isFirefox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') != -1;
var browser = null;
switch (true) {
    case isChrome:
        {
            browser = "chrome";
            break;
        }
    case isSafari:
        {
            browser = "safari";
            break;
        }
    case isFirefox:
        {
            browser = "firefox";
            break;
        }
}
```

My view is that much more explicit than multiple `else if`s. Do you think it's a good approach?

Comment: The else-if alternative is shorter and more explicit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming that you bad a bunch of boolean variables already defined, I think a chained ternary conditional expression would be even better, because it's more compact, and also emphasizes that the goal is to assigning *something* to `browser`.

```
var browser = isChrome ? "chrome" :
              isSafari ? "safari" :
              isFirefox ? "firefox" :
              null;
```

Also consider defining a `userAgentContains(…)` function to reduce redundancy.

Answer (score 4):

It kinda looks explicit, but it also looks... weird. Too much going on.

`if ... else if` (or 200_success's neat ternaries) is shorter and much more conventional, which is a good thing. And with a `switch` you've got to beware of fall-throughs.

In your example, though, I might simply do:

```
var browser = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/(chrome|safari|firefox)/) || [null])[0];
```

Which accomplishes the same thing, really.

Or, if you need to do other stuff, after getting the browser name, *then* you can use a switch if you want:

```
var match = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/(chrome|safari|firefox)/) || [];
switch( match[0] ) {
  case "chrome":
    ...
    break;
  case "safari":
    ...
    break;
  case "firefox":
    ...
    break;
  default:
    ...
}
```